# Google Apps Script : "if" loops with radio buttons & writing it in an existing spreadsheet

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using google apps script & google site, I'm trying to write down a form and get the answers in a spreadsheet.
Here is my work for now on :

```
    function doGet(){

var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Radio Button Demo');

var radio1 = app.createVerticalPanel();
var radio11 = app.createRadioButton('group1','Oui').setName('oui1').setId('oui1');
var radio12 = app.createRadioButton('group1','Non').setName('non1').setId('non1');
radio1.add(radio11).add(radio12);
app.add(radio1);

var radio2 = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('question2').setVisible(false);
var radio21 = app.createRadioButton('group2','Oui').setName('oui2').setId('oui2');
var radio22 = app.createRadioButton('group2','Non').setName('non2').setId('non2');
radio2.add(radio21).add(radio22);
app.add(radio2);

var radio3 = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('question3').setVisible(false);
var radio31 = app.createRadioButton('group3','Oui').setName('oui3').setId('oui3');
var radio32 = app.createRadioButton('group3','Non').setName('non3').setId('non3');
radio3.add(radio31).add(radio32);
app.add(radio3);

var radio4 = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('question4').setVisible(false);
var radio41 = app.createRadioButton('group4','Cool').setName('oui4').setId('oui4');
var radio42 = app.createRadioButton('group4','Or not').setName('non4').setId('non4');
radio4.add(radio41).add(radio42);
app.add(radio4);

// handler to make value of question 1 change
var handler11 = app.createServerValueChangeHandler('showstatus1_1');
handler11.addCallbackElement(radio1);
radio11.addValueChangeHandler(handler11);

var handler12 = app.createServerValueChangeHandler('showstatus1_2');
handler12.addCallbackElement(radio1);
radio12.addValueChangeHandler(handler12);

// handler to make value of question 2 change
var handler21 = app.createServerValueChangeHandler('showstatus2_1');
handler21.addCallbackElement(radio2);
radio21.addValueChangeHandler(handler21);

var handler22 = app.createServerValueChangeHandler('showstatus2_2');
handler22.addCallbackElement(radio2);
radio22.addValueChangeHandler(handler22);

// handler to make value of question 3 change
var handler31 = app.createServerValueChangeHandler('showstatus3_1');
handler31.addCallbackElement(radio3);
radio31.addValueChangeHandler(handler31);

var handler32 = app.createServerValueChangeHandler('showstatus3_2');
handler32.addCallbackElement(radio3);
radio32.addValueChangeHandler(handler32);

// handler to make value of question 4 change
var handler41 = app.createServerValueChangeHandler('showstatus4_1');
handler41.addCallbackElement(radio4);
radio41.addValueChangeHandler(handler41);

var handler42 = app.createServerValueChangeHandler('showstatus4_2');
handler42.addCallbackElement(radio4);
radio42.addValueChangeHandler(handler42);


// functions to change values of question 1
function showstatus1_1(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var radioValue = e.parameter.oui1 
  app.getElementById('non1').setValue(false);
  app.getElementById('question2').setVisible(true);
  return app;
}

function showstatus1_2(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var radioValue = e.parameter.non1;
  app.getElementById('oui1').setValue(false);
  app.getElementById('question2').setVisible(true);
  return app;
}

// functions to change values of question 2
function showstatus2_1(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var radioValue = e.parameter.oui2 
  app.getElementById('non2').setValue(false);
  return app;
}

function showstatus2_2(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var radioValue = e.parameter.non2;
  app.getElementById('oui2').setValue(false);
  return app;
}

// functions to change values of question 3
function showstatus3_1(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var radioValue = e.parameter.oui3 
  app.getElementById('non3').setValue(false);
  return app;
}

function showstatus3_2(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var radioValue = e.parameter.non3;
  app.getElementById('oui3').setValue(false);
  return app;
}

// functions to change values of question 4
function showstatus4_1(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var radioValue = e.parameter.oui4 
  app.getElementById('non4').setValue(false);
  return app;
}

function showstatus4_2(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var radioValue = e.parameter.non4;
  app.getElementById('oui4').setValue(false);
  return app;
}
```

My first question is How to make question 3 and 4 visible based on the answers of question 1 and 2. I have found how to do it based on the answer of 1 question but I'm stuck with multiple questions.
For example : Make question 3 visible if the answer is "Oui" and "Oui", else make question 4 visible !

My second question is : How to get the value of the different questions ?
I would like to write in an existing spreadsheet the answers oof the different users, and also the choice. But i'm stuck when I try to find a way of getting the answers of users.

Thanks for helping me if you have time,
Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

radioButtons are a bit tricky in GAS... to work as they should, they need to have the same name but if they have the same name they return a result in the handler function that can't be read, ie e.parameter.radioButtonName is not useable since they are not differentiated.
There are simple workarounds though. Here is an example to show how you could handle that using clientHandlers and a (visible or invisible) textBox. there is also a function that handles the "reverse process", ie set the radioButtons vale from data coming from another widget. That should help you so answer both of your questions.

```
function radiotest() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var radioValue = app.createTextBox().setId('radioValue');
      radioValue.setId("radioValue").setName("radioValue");
  var listhandler = app.createServerHandler('listhandler').addCallbackElement(panel); 
  var list = app.createListBox().addChangeHandler(listhandler).setName('list');    
  for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    var name = 'choice '+i;
    list.addItem('Activate '+name,name);
    var handler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(radioValue).setText(name);
    panel.add(app.createRadioButton('radioButtonGroup',name).addValueChangeHandler(handler).setId(name));
  }
  panel.add(radioValue);
  var getit=app.createButton("Valide").setId("val");
  panel.add(getit).add(list);             
  var handler = app.createServerHandler("valide");
  handler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  getit.addClickHandler(handler);
  app.add(panel);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);// show app 
}
//
function valide(e){ ;// This function is called when key "validate" is pressed 
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var RadioButton = e.parameter.radioValue;               
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue(RadioButton);
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  return app;
}​

function listhandler(e){ ;// This function is called when listBox is changed
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var listvalue = e.parameter.list;
  var radioValue = app.getElementById('radioValue').setValue(listvalue);
  sh.getRange('A2').setValue(listvalue);
  var radiobutton = app.getElementById(listvalue);
  radiobutton.setValue(true);
return app;
}​
```

Run this test from a spreadsheet and you'll get something like this :

[image]

---

**EDIT :**

following your comment, here is an efficient way to build such a multiple choices questionary, [here is the test app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbziAO3gmMA8bs_BbLCspiPfQ20JSGfxMgHAcfD8AG_0p2dxMso/exec)

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('test Questionnaire');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var sHdlr = app.createServerHandler('react').addCallbackElement(panel);
  var questions = ['<b>Question Numéro 1 :</b><br>Faites votre choix parmis les 4 possibilités suivantes','<b>Question 2</b><br>Encore un fois, faites votre choix','<b>Question 3</b><br>encore un effort...','<b>Question 4</b><br>vous y êtes presque...'];
  var Qitems = [['choix1 de Q1','choix2 de Q1','choix3 de Q1','choix4 de Q1'],['choix1 de Q2','choix2 de Q2','choix3 de Q2','choix4 de Q2'],
  ['choix1 de Q3','choix2 de Q3','choix3 de Q3','choix4 de Q3'],['choix1 de Q4','choix2 de Q4','choix3 de Q4','choix4 de Q4']];
  var Qpanel = [];
  for (var n=0 ; n<questions.length ; ++n){
    var Qval = app.createTextBox().setId('Qvalue'+n).setName('Qvalue'+n).setVisible(false);
    Qpanel[n] = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('QP'+n).setVisible(false).add(app.createHTML(questions[n])).add(Qval).setStyleAttribute('padding','10px');
    panel.add(Qpanel[n]);
    for(var q=0;q<Qitems[n].length;++q){
      var name = Qitems[n][q]
      var handler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(Qval).setText(name);
      Qpanel[n].add(app.createRadioButton('radioButtonQ'+n,name).addClickHandler(handler).setId(name).addClickHandler(sHdlr));
    }
    }
    app.add(panel);
    Qpanel[0].setVisible(true);
    return app;
}

function react(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var source = e.parameter.source;
  var answer = [];
  for(var n = 0; n < 4 ; ++n){
    answer[n] = e.parameter['Qvalue'+n];
    Logger.log('answer '+ (n+1) + ' = '+answer[n]+' source = '+source)
    }
      if(answer[0]=='choix1 de Q1'){app.getElementById('QP'+1).setVisible(true)}
      if(answer[1]=='choix1 de Q2'||answer[1]=='choix3 de Q2'){app.getElementById('QP'+2).setVisible(true)}
      if(answer[2]=='choix1 de Q3'||answer[2]=='choix3 de Q3'){app.getElementById('QP'+3).setVisible(true)}
      if(answer[3]=='choix1 de Q4'){
      app.add(app.createHTML('YESSSSSSSSS ... !!<br>Vous avez réussi !<br> vos réponses sont les suivantes : '+answer.join('  +  ')).setStyleAttribute('padding','20px'))
      }
  return app;
}
```

Comment: OMG, they forgot to implement the `.getValue()` method for `RadioButton` . In GWT you use that method to get the current value :)) . Did you open an issue on the bug tracker?

Comment: Issue is open for a couple of years now...:-)  not sure it will ever change! But the workaround is quite easy.

Comment: Thanks Serge insas. I manage to get an application working as a web app. I'll try to adapt it to set question to visible or invisible.

Comment: Well, it's me again...

I've created another multiple choice question, just like the first one proposed by @Sergeinsas, and set it to invisble at first.
What I want to do is to set it to visible if, for example, the first choice of the first question is selected. Otherwise I let it to invisible.

I've tried to use and If loop with e.parameter.radioValue and the .toString, but it doesn't seems to work :/

Comment: see edit with a full code for 4 question showing up one by one. I wrote this in a spreadsheet bounded script deployed as a webapp to I can easily get the answers in the same sheet, everything in the same place is quite nice for maintenance. Since you seem to speak french I made my questions "hybrid" ^^ *choix1 de Q1* but *thank you* ha ha...

Comment: Thanks a lot Serge insas !
I can't really realize yet how far I am to get to know GAS... You made it in few lines whereas I didn't manage to make it work in 3000 lines or so ^^ I'll test it asap and will be back if I need another explanation.

I speak french and I am french ^^ Thanks for the great questions ;)

Comment: I learned about everything I know reading and answering questions and answers on this forum and on the old one so I guess you'll find a lot of helpful subjects around here... don't hesitate to ask, there are a few very generous people here that are ready to share their knowledge,I'm a pure 'amateur' but my enthusiasm has been rewarded :-) et puis j'avais justement besoin d'un nouveau formulaire à choix multiples, votre question tombait pile ! Vous verrez, GAS is really nice to work with...good luck

Comment: Btw, if you need more info on this, please start a new thread, people don't like to read too long posts:-)